# What is best queue system for building reminder applicaiton

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging

I was looking into rabbitmq to build simple reminder application to send emails. I liked idea of priority and thought I can use the timestamp as one but when check the docs it says only can be used number between 1-255.

Is there any other queue I can use to achieve receiving messages based on smallest number of priority but will not have limit as rabbitmq?

Comment: It looks like you need a timer queue or timer service.

Comment: are there open source timer queues similar to rabbitmq ?

Comment: Look at the cadenceworkflow.io. But is is much more than the queue :)

Comment: You need a database, not a queue.